# validate statement using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have written a regular expression to check the validation for the below statements

```
String pattern= "^how many [r|R]upees is (([A-Za-z\\s])+)\\?$";

String statment1 = "HOW MANY RUPEES IS RED BLUE GOLD ?"; // all caps
String statment2 = "how many Rupees is red blue Gold?";
System.out.println(statment1.matches(pattern));
System.out.println(statment2.matches(pattern));
```

**Output**

```
false
true
```

How to validate if the statement if everything is under caps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `(?i)` case-insensitive modifier to your pattern.

```
String pattern = "(?i)^how many rupees is ([a-z\\s]+)\\?$";
```

Comment: where did you learn regex? every time I open a regex tag I see your answer with lots of upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this without regex by using the StringUtils [isAllUpperCase](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isAllUpperCase(java.lang.CharSequence))

> Checks if the CharSequence contains only uppercase characters.

```
!StringUtils.isAllUpperCase("HOW MANY RUPEES IS RED BLUE GOLD ?") = false
!StringUtils.isAllUpperCase("how many Rupees is red blue gold?") = true
```

Comment: I think the OP means to get `statement1` to match the given regex, not just test for upper case.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Actually I went with this line `How to validate if the statement if everything is under caps`. If thats not the case then Avinash's answer is good enough.